# Here is my login form How Do I disable submit button if the input field is empty?

Tags: html

Here is my login form How Do I disable submit button if the input field is empty ?

[This is my login page.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUcYH.png)

[submit button works if the input field is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Hir.png)

```
<div class="login-form">
  <form action="/login" method="POST">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <!-- input fields start from here -->
    <div class="content">
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="nope" name="email">
      </div>
      <div class="input-field">
        <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" name="password">
      </div>    
<!-- Action links -->
      <a href="#" class="link">Forgot Your Password?</a>
      <br>
      <a href="register" class="link">Create an Account</a>
    </div>
<!-- submit buttons -->
    <div class="action">
      <button type="submit" >Sign in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required) attribute to each `<input>`. If any `<input>` is empty and the submit event is triggered, the submitting process will be stopped and a hint will popup to notify the user of an empty `<input>` needing data. See **Example A**.

If you really want the button disabled then see **Example B**, details are commented in the example.

### Example A

```html
<form>
  <input required>
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

### Example B

```js
// Bind the first <form> to the input event
document.forms[0].oninput = enableButton;

function enableButton(e) {
  // Reference all form controls
  const IO = this.elements;
  // Collect all [name='data'] into an array
  const inputs = [...IO.data];
  
  /*
  If every input has at least 1 character as .value...
  ...enable the button...
  ...otherwise disable the button
  */
  if (inputs.every(input => input.value.length > 0)) {
    IO.btn.disabled = false;
  } else {
    IO.btn.disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input name='data'>
  <input name='data'><br>
  <button id='btn' disabled>Submit</button>
</form>
```